# flutter icon as background with overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to recreate the weather app design from this link [UI design](https://uibundle.com/products/963-weath-io-clean-weather-v2-free-adobe-xd-file). However i'm stuck at creating the huge Icon that is overflowing in the background. I tried to use a stack and add an Icon widget with very big size. However, the icon will change its position when the size is changed. So it moves from the center. Any idea on how to get the background result as in the design?

Edit:

I tried the code below. However the icon will move if the screen size of the device changes. Is there away to have this look the same on every screen size?

```
Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: -250,
              top: -100,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.ac_unit,
                size: 900,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
            ),
```

Which gives me the result below.
[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use the widget: `OverflowBox`

The [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html)  explains OverflowBox as:

> A widget that imposes different constraints on its child than it gets from its parent, possibly allowing the child to overflow the parent.

##### Example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Overflow Box',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Stack(children: [

          OverflowBox(
            // Specify the maxWidth and maxHeight and it works
            // regardless of orientation.
            maxWidth: 800,
            maxHeight: 800,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.ac_unit,
              size: 800,
              color: Colors.black.withAlpha(80),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Image of the code in action:

[image: Centered large icon using OverflowBox]

Answer (score 1):

Using `Stack` is fine. Did you use `Positioned` or `Align` to wrap the `Icon` widget, to control its position?

For example, your widget hierarchy could be something like: `Stack > Align > Icon`.

In the `Align` widget, you can specify how it aligns in the Stack. The values are `(x, y)` ranging from `-1` to `+1`, with `0` being the center. For example, you can use `alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5)` to make it center horizontally, and 50% towards the top on the vertical axis.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately this didn't work. When you set the icon to a big size like 800 aligment does not seem to have any effect on it. The icon stays in the same place.

Comment: @nourdin Oh wow, you were talking about icons in the background, not the small icons... Your edit to the question made it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use Positioned widget, you can actually positioned based on screen height and width and then warp in [FractionalTranslation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionalTranslation-class.html) to center it from its given size,

lets calculate with simple way :
[image]

code :

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
          child: FractionalTranslation(
              translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
              child: child()),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think that you miss understood the question. I was asking about the icon in the background. Not the Icon were you drew the yellow lines. If you look closely you will see the same Icon in background with a huge size.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer that @Tor-Martin Holen suggested, but I would adjust the **maxWidth** and **size** attributes to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to adjust to different screens.

Comment: This doesn't work. The icon will move off center when the size of the icon becomes bigger than the screen size.